# VIM with iA Writer type formatting?

Tags: vim, formatting, markdown

I've been Googling for a while now. I would like to have [iA Writer](http://www.iawriter.com/)-like (or a bit like StackExchange) formatting in Vim. Since I love the way it formats my texts, but I'm constantly pressing "w" to skip words because my experience with Vim. I would love to be able to have the same smart formatting in Vim.

I did found a nice Vim plugin for getting Vim to toggle to big and clean font: 
https://github.com/honza/writer.vim

But this still does not enable me to use the formatting:

```
# Header 1  
## Header 2 
*underline*
**strong**
etc...
```

Besides all this above, I would not mind to have Vim like shortcuts in my iA writer app if it would not be possible to implement iA formatting in Vim.

**Edit**: After a while of even more searching, I found out this type of formatting is called [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). I am starting to think there isn't really a good way to directly edit a Markdown file in Vim, because Vim is not able to make things display like that? I would really like to be able to use the movement shortcuts in combination of the nice formatting of Markdown and how it is displayed in iA Writer.

Comment: For people who don't know what that thing is or what it does, could you provide examples of what it does and how it does them?

Comment: Markdown is plain text and Vim is the best tool you'll ever find for editing plain text. The presentation of markdown is an entirely different problem. The `##` and Co. are there to provide semantics to your text for humans and machines. If you have `## subheader`, you don't need to have a 22px font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Andersson [says](https://superuser.com/a/456235/907), a syntax file will get you a long way towards what you want. It's still not the same as a [WYSIWYG editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG), but headings, bold or italic text and code *will* look different if you have a proper syntax file set up. Note that there are a few competing Markdown plugins. In addition to the one Daniel mentioned, you might try [this one](https://github.com/sukima/vim-markdown) or [this one](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown).

But in addition, you could try a plugin for Vim like [WriteRoom for Vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2231). The idea is to make Vim visually distraction free. If you add such a plugin, and make (g)Vim as large as possible, you may get even closer to what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I think with the syntaxes that you've provided, and also the one of Daniel Andersson, I'll get pretty close to where I would like to be. The only thing I'm missing now (which isn't really a big problem) is the indentation that iA Writer gives me. Thanks to both of you! Vim just also became my preference for simple text editing and creating notes. :)

Answer (score 2):

Vim is a text editor and not a word processor. By design it does not allow to show portions of text with a larger font.

Close enough, though, is to write your documents with Markdown syntax, and use a syntax file that highlights correct Markdown markup in Vim with color/font style/etc.

[Vim Instant Markdown](https://github.com/suan/vim-instant-markdown) provides an instant preview mode in an external window.

[This Vim syntax plugin for Markdown](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2882) seems to be well used.

Also worth to mention: the point of Markdown syntax is that it is supposed to be easy to read even without fancy graphics possibilities; i.e. it should be readable as a well organized document in raw text form. If it fulfills this or not is a matter of opinion, but I find it quite clear, and I often write personal notes that will never be shown in a fancy graphical manner in Markdown syntax (on the other hand, I don't find LaTeX syntax especially difficult to read on the fly either).